# Draw on a UIImage

Tags: iphone, macos, uiimage, core-graphics

I'm attempting to create a UIImage and save it to the photo gallery, the image gets created but it's just a plane white with no color what so ever. Any ideas?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320,420));
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init];

[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

UIImage *newImage;    
newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:ctx:), nil);
```

Also just to add to the above. I added this line:

```
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

And now I get a grey image, still no rectangle, but it's something different so thought it might help

Comment: Just so you know, lines 3-5 do nothing. You're filling an empty path.

Comment: That was part of my debug- I was trying to get something to show, it's removed since then. So any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What UIImage are you trying to show?, this code only initialized a space of memory but it's filled with nothing, use [UIImage imageNamed:@"..."]; where the string is some file the resources for your project. Then once you have opened and drawn the image in the context you will be able to draw a string or whatever over it.

Also make sure that you close the context once you have gotten the image from it.

Comment: I'm trying to create a new image and draw to it, I'm not trying to paint over an existing image. I thought [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
 draws a rectangle at the specified coords?

Comment: you are creating an UIImage that has nothing in it though. If you create a rectangle using CGRectMake and then color it, etc, you can use this code:                                                      CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 15.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, 
         [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(60,300,650,400);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);